# Conversion of sql statemnt in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a sql Statement with multiple cases now I have to write the statement in Dax 
I tried using switch but the output is not same
the sql statement  :

```
CASE WHEN @STRIKER!='' OR @NONSTRIKER!='' THEN   (RUNS + (CASE WHEN BYES = 0 AND LEGBYES = 0 THEN OVERTHROW ELSE 0 END))            
             WHEN @BOWLER!='' THEN (RUNS + WIDE+ (CASE WHEN BALL.NOBALL > 0 AND (BALL.BYES > 0 OR BALL.LEGBYES > 0) THEN BALL.BYES + BALL.NOBALL + BALL.LEGBYES            
                        WHEN BALL.NOBALL > 0 AND BALL.BYES = 0 AND BALL.LEGBYES = 0 THEN BALL.NOBALL            
                        ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN BYES = 0 AND LEGBYES = 0 THEN OVERTHROW ELSE 0 END))            
             ELSE GRANDTOTAL END ) AS RUNS
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Your post does not contain a question. Please state clearly what you are trying to do, and what you require from SO users to help with.

Comment: I am trying to convert the sql statement to DAX using switch statement but i am not able to convert the total sql statement as one switch statement so i need help how can i write the sql statement in power bi DAX??

Comment: Please EDIT you question with that information, don't just start providing tidbits of extra information in a comment.

Comment: First, I think you need to simplify the case statement

Comment: Hi Javeed, It would also be useful to have a schema of the tables involved, and the WHOLE sql statement, rather than a snippit  (apologies for the first comment, I've tried to provide an answer below)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would simplify the case statement,

I assume you have the case statements because NULLS can exist in your result?   you could simply try

```
RUNS + 
WIDE + 
ISNULL(BALL.NOBALL,0) + 
ISNULL(BALL.BYES,0) + 
ISNULL(BALL.LEGBYES,0) + 
ISNULL(OVERTHROW,0)
```

But if you've already got the model in PowerBI with those columns listed, you could simply add a calculated column that would sum all the columns which would ignore the nulls...

```
Total = RUNS + WIDE + NOBALL + BYES + LEGBYES + OVERTHROW
```

?  but without the schema, its really hard to know what the solution might be.

good luck!